# Is there an "integer" version of "quotedstr" to be used in Delphi 2010

Tags: mysql, delphi-2010

`QuotedStr()` is used to enter string values into an SQL query in Delphi 2010, and I'm wondering if such a thing exists for integer values. For example:

```pascal
qryRes.Close;
qryRes.SQL.Text := 'Insert INTO Reservaatdetails (MaxcusperRes)VALUES(' + QuotedStr(ownobjek.getMaks) + ' ) ';
qryRes.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Bit pointless just use IntToStr. How many spaces do you expect to find in an integer? Far better to use parameters anyway.

Comment: In SQL, quote characters are needed only for string literals, you don't need them for integer literals. `IntToStr()` will suffice.